# How to open up comments to all visitors

Tags: comments

The "Leave a Reply" section at the bottom of my pages is asking for a login before visitors can comment. Is there any way I can turn this off so anybody can leave a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to yoursite... /wp-admin/options-discussion.php

Is `Users must be registered and logged in to comment` selected? 
If so, unselect it and `Save Changes`.